# Wait _app.js loaded then run component on Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, next.js

I'm using Next.js to develop a website.
I need to use the JavaScript SDK to connect the user login.

I decided to init the SDK in `_app.js` because I think that It should be the first file the server load.
so I wrote these code in `_app.js`

```
componentDidMount () {
    window.mySDK = new userInfoSDK()
    console.log('_app')
 }
```

and wrote something like this in `page.js`

```
async componentDidMount () {
   console.log('page')
   const loginStatus = await window.mySDK.getInfo()
 }
```

and I get the result is `window.mySDK is not defined`

The console shows

`page
_app.js`

so that mean the `page.js` component is mounted before the `_app.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ComponentDiDMount is invoked once, only on the client (not on the
>   server), immediately after the initial rendering occurs. At this point
>   in the lifecycle, you can access any refs to your children (e.g., to
>   access the underlying DOM representation). The componentDidMount()
>   method of child components is invoked before that of parent
>   components.

I think for your use case you can initialize your SDK on another REACT hook or in constructor to make sure it will be executed before.

Comment: The SDK will use the `window` object so I think that it should only run on client side.

Comment: Yes but try to use `process.browser` to check is you are in browser or server and not use comonentDidMount

Comment: Are provided solutions works for you or you have another troubles related to this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [React lifecycle](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) `componentDidMount` run after `render`. Saying that, it means it run the render first and then `componentDidMount`.

Simple solution:
in `_app.js` write your code in constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log('_app')
  }
```

You don't need to change anything in `page.js`.

in this case, the **_app** run *first* and then **other pages**.

the output will be

```
_app.js
page
```